# Change clone directory for gitlab runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Currently I am facing path issues in multiple tools, because of the path length for gitlab clone dir, using gitlab runner.
**Current dir structure:
C:\gitLab\builds\576aef34\0\root\TEST**

**Is there any way to shorten this path, to like:
C:\gitLab\builds\TEST**

Comment: Why was this downvoted ?

Comment: Related: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/changing-the-build-intermediate-paths-for-gitlab-runner (doe not provide an answer to this question yet).

Comment: Quite old thread, but nowdays https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64089704/gitlab-runner-change-builds-dir seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the only thing you can do is change the `build_dir` path but not the relative paths.

Comment: I added this `build_dir` on my `.gitlab-ci.yml`, it if GitLab failed with this error: `Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml: jobs:run_tests config contains unknown keys: build_dir`. From where I can find an example of this `build_dir` setting?

Comment: @user Take https://github.com/nanoporetech/scrappie/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L10 as an example.

Comment: Actually, OP should be able to save 2 levels of depth if setting `build_dir` to the drive root which will give **C:\576aef34\0\root\TEST** - probably not bad, but still 1 level higher than asked in the question... :)