# Gitlab-runner change builds_dir

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My default builds_dir on the production server is   `/root/builds/qL8eZYTH/0/faramarzqoshchi/testing_gitlab_runner/` which i want it to be `/home/[domain_name]/public_html/test_build` which is for my **test stage**.
i've defined the **builds_dir** variable in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` with `/home/[domain_name]/public_html/test_build` value, but it still doesn't push the `testing_gitlab_runner` project to `/home/[domain_name]/public_html/test_build`.

am i doing everything correctly? is this the right way to push different stages like test and production to server?

OS: Centos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#custom-build-directories), you'll have to also enable the `custom_build_dir` setting, which is by default only enabled for docker and kubernetes executors:

```
[runners.custom_build_dir]
  enabled = true
```

[See here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnerscustom_build_dir-section) for more info regarding this setting.

Also you should try to set the variable `$GIT_CLONE_PATH`:

```
variables:
  GIT_CLONE_PATH: $CI_BUILDS_DIR/project-name

test:
  script:
    - pwd
```

> The GIT_CLONE_PATH has to always be within $CI_BUILDS_DIR. The directory set in $CI_BUILDS_DIR is dependent on executor and configuration of runners.builds_dir setting.

> This can only be used when custom_build_dir is enabled in the runner’s configuration. This is the default configuration for the docker and kubernetes executors.

[Source](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#custom-build-directories)

---

So in your specific case I would try this in your `config.toml`:

```
builds_dir = "/home/[domain_name]/public_html/test_build"

[runners.custom_build_dir]
  enabled = true
```

And add this to the top of your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
  GIT_CLONE_PATH: $CI_BUILDS_DIR/testing_gitlab_runner
```